# Android device won't wake up on long idle with push notifications

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-cloud-messaging

We are building an app that receives push notifications from Google play services (transferred from GCM few days ago).

Our problem is that on some devices, after sleeping for more than about 15 min the push is not arriving, even if WiFi and 3G are on.

No matter what we do - flags on server(time_to_live, delay on idle etc.), transferring from GCM to play services, checking the right permissions in app manifest. Nothing helps.

When the device is not in sleep mode the notifications comes fine.

This issue disturbs us very much.

Will be glad for help or suggestions.

Thanks,

Noam

Comment: How long have you waited to see if the push notification arrives?

Answer (score 0):

Since your needs are rather sporadic, holding a wake lock, even a partial one, would most likely be a very bad choice in terms of battery usage. A better approach would be to set an alarm to periodically wake up and run a small service to check for messages. I suspect that if you waited long enough, something else would wake up the device and you'd get your message.

Edit 1:

That said, you still might need the `android.permission.WAKE_LOCK` permission to keep the device awake long enough to process the message before going back to sleep. At least you apparently did with GCM.

Edit 2:
You might also be experiencing the results of an [apparent bug with the heartbeat interval](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/nexus/fslYqYrULto%5B1-25-false%5D) that affects users with some carriers/routers.

Comment: As for #1, we already added wake lock. Didn't help. Will try to research #2 and let you know. Thanks.